# Volumn definition in high dimensional Euclidean space?

Tags: probability, geometry, measure-theory

This may be a simple question to some folks, but I've searched for quite a while without finding a definitive answer, so I figure I'd ask/confirm it here.  My apology if it was answered before.  In that case, I'd greatly appreciate a link/reference.

(1) Does the following constitute ***the*** formal definition of the volumn of some arbitrary shape (subset) $\Omega$ in $\mathbb R^k$ Euclidean space?

$\mathrm{vol}(\Omega) \triangleq \int_{\Omega} 1 \:dx_1dx_2...dx_k$

Or are there other definitions for other applications/purposes?

(2) What's the motivation behind this definition?  Is it just to be consistent with our usual notion of volumn of square, circle, ball, ... etc in $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$?  Does it also has to do with the definition of multi-variate probability density function (pdf) in probability theory?  It appears to me that this definition also works nicely/naturally with the pdf, since we require

$$\int f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_k) dx_1 dx_2...dx_k = 1.$$

So, for example, if $(X_1, ..., X_k)$ are random variables uniformly distributed in $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^k$, i.e. $f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_k)=c$ for $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_k)\in \Omega$ (and zero elsewhere), then

$$1=\int_{\Omega} f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_k) dx_1 dx_2...dx_k=c\:\mathrm{vol}(\Omega).$$

Therefore, the probability density is $c=\frac{1}{\mathrm{vol}(\Omega)}$ over $\Omega$, which is consistent with our usual notion of density.

Are there other important motivations/considerations that I missed?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your comments are consistent with the idea of generalising the concept of a (hyper)volume of a (hyper)cuboid when both are $k$-dimensional.  But it gets more complicated when you are considering for example a uniform distribution on $\Omega = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3): x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=1\} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ the surface of a unit sphere, where the surface has a 3D-volume of $\mathrm{vol}(\Omega)=0$